# Css form progress bar styling issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this snippet of code,

```
    <style media="screen">
    div,
    span {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .amg-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }
    .amg-progress-bar {
    display: flex;
    }
    .amg-step {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 249px;
    color: #999;
    }
    .amg-step_marker {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .amg-step_marker_content {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
    }
    .amg-step_marker_icon {
    display: none;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    }
    .amg-step_wing {
    width: calc(100% - 32px + 8px);
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 13px + 50px / 2);
    bottom: 21px;
    border-top: 4px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #ddd;
    z-index: 1;
    }
    .amg-step:last-child .amg-step_wing {
    display: none;
    }
    .amg-step.\--active {
    color: #ff8d00;
    }
    .amg-step.\--active .amg-step_marker:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px #ff8d00;
    }
    .amg-step.\--active .amg-step_marker_content {
    background-color: #ff8d00;
    color: #fff;
    }
    .amg-step.\--active .amg-step_wing {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff8d00, #dddddd);
    }
    .amg-step.\--complete .amg-step_marker {
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .amg-step.\--complete .amg-step_marker:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px #39d084;
    }
    .amg-step.\--complete .amg-step_marker_content {
    background-color: #39d084;
    color: #fff;
    }
    .amg-step.\--complete .amg-step_marker_number {
    display: none;
    }
    .amg-step.\--complete .amg-step_marker_icon {
    display: block;
    }
    .amg-step.\--complete .amg-step_wing {
    background-color: #39d084;
    }
    .amg-step.\--previous .amg-step_wing {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #39d084, #ff8d00);
    }

    </style>
    <div class="amg-container">
      <div class="amg-progress-bar">
        <div class="amg-step --complete">
          <div class="amg-step_marker">
            <div class="amg-step_marker_content">
              <div class="amg-step_marker_number">1</div>
              <div class="amg-step_marker_icon">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792"><path d="M1671 566q0 40-28 68l-724 724-136 136q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-136-136-362-362q-28-28-28-68t28-68l136-136q28-28 68-28t68 28l294 295 656-657q28-28 68-28t68 28l136 136q28 28 28 68z" fill="#fff"/></svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="amg-step_wing"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="amg-step --active">
          <div class="amg-step_marker">
            <div class="amg-step_marker_content">
              <span class="amg-step_marker_number">2</span>
              <div class="amg-step_marker_icon">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792"><path d="M1671 566q0 40-28 68l-724 724-136 136q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-136-136-362-362q-28-28-28-68t28-68l136-136q28-28 68-28t68 28l294 295 656-657q28-28 68-28t68 28l136 136q28 28 28 68z" fill="#fff"/></svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="amg-step_wing"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="amg-step">
          <div class="amg-step_marker">
            <div class="amg-step_marker_content">
              <span class="amg-step_marker_number">3</span>
              <div class="amg-step_marker_icon">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792"><path d="M1671 566q0 40-28 68l-724 724-136 136q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-136-136-362-362q-28-28-28-68t28-68l136-136q28-28 68-28t68 28l294 295 656-657q28-28 68-28t68 28l136 136q28 28 28 68z" fill="#fff"/></svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="amg-step_wing"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="amg-step">
          <div class="amg-step_wing"></div>
          <div class="amg-step_marker">
            <div class="amg-step_marker_content">
              <span class="amg-step_marker_number">4</span>
              <div class="amg-step_marker_icon">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792"><path d="M1671 566q0 40-28 68l-724 724-136 136q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-136-136-362-362q-28-28-28-68t28-68l136-136q28-28 68-28t68 28l294 295 656-657q28-28 68-28t68 28l136 136q28 28 28 68z" fill="#fff"/></svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="amg-step">
          <div class="amg-step_wing"></div>
          <div class="amg-step_marker">
            <div class="amg-step_marker_content">
              <span class="amg-step_marker_number">5</span>
              <div class="amg-step_marker_icon">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792"><path d="M1671 566q0 40-28 68l-724 724-136 136q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-136-136-362-362q-28-28-28-68t28-68l136-136q28-28 68-28t68 28l294 295 656-657q28-28 68-28t68 28l136 136q28 28 28 68z" fill="#fff"/></svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Which currently displays this [image: image of progress bar]

I'm able to change the progress bar with the min-width so it looks like this (changed numbers from 120px to 249px)

[image: 2nd image with correct width]

The issue is, Using pc doesnt allow for differnet style screens to see the width correctly e.g. i'm developing on a mac screen but when i transfer it to my 2nd screen (a 27inch) it doesnt display correctly!

I've tried changing the px to a % which hasnt worked.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just answered it with this!

Works fine with the code below

```
    <style media="screen">
    div,
    span {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .amg-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }
    .amg-progress-bar {
    display: flex;
    }
    .amg-step {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 20%;
    color: #999;
    }
    .amg-step_marker {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .amg-step_marker_content {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
    }
    .amg-step_marker_icon {
    display: none;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    }
    .amg-step_wing {
    width: calc(100% - 32px + 8px);
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 13px + 50px / 2);
    bottom: 21px;
    border-top: 4px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #ddd;
    z-index: 1;
    }
    .amg-step:last-child .amg-step_wing {
    display: none;
    }
    .amg-step.\--active {
    color: #ff8d00;
    }
    .amg-step.\--active .amg-step_marker:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px #ff8d00;
    }
    .amg-step.\--active .amg-step_marker_content {
    background-color: #ff8d00;
    color: #fff;
    }
    .amg-step.\--active .amg-step_wing {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff8d00, #dddddd);
    }
    .amg-step.\--complete .amg-step_marker {
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .amg-step.\--complete .amg-step_marker:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px #39d084;
    }
    .amg-step.\--complete .amg-step_marker_content {
    background-color: #39d084;
    color: #fff;
    }
    .amg-step.\--complete .amg-step_marker_number {
    display: none;
    }
    .amg-step.\--complete .amg-step_marker_icon {
    display: block;
    }
    .amg-step.\--complete .amg-step_wing {
    background-color: #39d084;
    }
    .amg-step.\--previous .amg-step_wing {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #39d084, #ff8d00);
    }

    </style>
    <div class="amg-container">
      <div class="amg-progress-bar" style="width:100%">
        <div class="amg-step --complete">
          <div class="amg-step_marker">
            <div class="amg-step_marker_content">
              <div class="amg-step_marker_number">1</div>
              <div class="amg-step_marker_icon">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792"><path d="M1671 566q0 40-28 68l-724 724-136 136q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-136-136-362-362q-28-28-28-68t28-68l136-136q28-28 68-28t68 28l294 295 656-657q28-28 68-28t68 28l136 136q28 28 28 68z" fill="#fff"/></svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="amg-step_wing"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="amg-step --active">
          <div class="amg-step_marker">
            <div class="amg-step_marker_content">
              <span class="amg-step_marker_number">2</span>
              <div class="amg-step_marker_icon">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792"><path d="M1671 566q0 40-28 68l-724 724-136 136q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-136-136-362-362q-28-28-28-68t28-68l136-136q28-28 68-28t68 28l294 295 656-657q28-28 68-28t68 28l136 136q28 28 28 68z" fill="#fff"/></svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="amg-step_wing"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="amg-step">
          <div class="amg-step_marker">
            <div class="amg-step_marker_content">
              <span class="amg-step_marker_number">3</span>
              <div class="amg-step_marker_icon">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792"><path d="M1671 566q0 40-28 68l-724 724-136 136q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-136-136-362-362q-28-28-28-68t28-68l136-136q28-28 68-28t68 28l294 295 656-657q28-28 68-28t68 28l136 136q28 28 28 68z" fill="#fff"/></svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="amg-step_wing"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="amg-step">
          <div class="amg-step_wing"></div>
          <div class="amg-step_marker">
            <div class="amg-step_marker_content">
              <span class="amg-step_marker_number">4</span>
              <div class="amg-step_marker_icon">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792"><path d="M1671 566q0 40-28 68l-724 724-136 136q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-136-136-362-362q-28-28-28-68t28-68l136-136q28-28 68-28t68 28l294 295 656-657q28-28 68-28t68 28l136 136q28 28 28 68z" fill="#fff"/></svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="amg-step">
          <div class="amg-step_wing"></div>
          <div class="amg-step_marker">
            <div class="amg-step_marker_content">
              <span class="amg-step_marker_number">5</span>
              <div class="amg-step_marker_icon">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792"><path d="M1671 566q0 40-28 68l-724 724-136 136q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-136-136-362-362q-28-28-28-68t28-68l136-136q28-28 68-28t68 28l294 295 656-657q28-28 68-28t68 28l136 136q28 28 28 68z" fill="#fff"/></svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

For people who cant see the change its a `width:100%` on the progress bar and `minwidth:20%`

Answer (score -1):

Try using a media query to specify widths at different screen sizes.